# Java: How to make a 2D array of a particular object

Tags: java, oop

I have the following class in Java:

```
public class Cell {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int g;
    private int h;
    public Cell(int x, int y, int g, int h) {
       this.x = x;
       this.y = y;
       this.g = g;
       this.h = h;
    }
}
```

I want to make a 2D array with each element of the array being of type Cell. However, I am not sure what is the best way to go about doing this. Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: `Cell[][] cells = new Cell[10][];` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Cell[][]` is this. Note however, this is slightly different to a 2-D array. It is actually a 1-D array, whose elements all have the type `Cell[]`. This means that your array does not have to be "rectangular".

`Cell[][] cells = new Cell[10][10];` does what you'd expect, and creates a 10x10 rectangular array.

However, you can do the following:

```
Cell[][] cells = new Cell[10][];
cells[0] = new Cell[1];
cells[1] = new Cell[1000];
...

cells[1][5] = 1;  // allowed, since cells[1] is a Cell[] of size 1000
cells[0][5] = 1;  // throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, since cells[0] has size 1
```

This can help if you are trying to represent, for example, triangular data structures (Pascal's triangle for example).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i suppose that Array wuldn't be handy, fixed size etc. Maybe using extra class with Collections in fields will be more OOP-style and convinient.

```
class Board {

    List<List<Cell>> hash;

    public Cell getCell(int x, int y) {
        // might be usefull to copy return value for immutability of hash
        return hash.get(x).get(y);
    }

    public void setCell(Cell cell, int x, int y) {
        this.hash.get(x).set(y, cell);
    }


}
```

Comment: This does not create a 2-D List. This creates 2 1-D Lists. If you wanted to dynamically grow your 2-D data structure, a List<List<Cell>> would work.

Comment: @cameron1024 right, silly misstake, time to sleep